# Save multiple Redux states

Tags: redux, react-redux

In developing my app I have been asked to create a save and restore functionality where the restore would provide a menu of previously stored states.

Ie. before the first save, restore is not possible.  After the first save Restore provides a link that will rehydrate to exactly that state. The user should be able to indicate a name for that saved state that would appear in the "restore" menu.

I feel like localStorage becomes a critical piece of this and had originally hoped that redux-storage would be part of the solution. From what I can tell, the Redux-Storage pattern is primarily about persistence, not serialization with keys.    Significant googling hasn't shown me any other modules that would work.

Is there an established pattern/module for solving this pattern.

Comment: What about a Command pattern? The classic use case for it is undo/redo. It should be possible to implement a variation with redux using actions as commands.

Comment: @SrThompson I'll need to brush up on Command Pattern for exact details  but at a high level, are you suggesting that each of the saved states become an encapsulated child of the "top of house" state?  Like: `states: [{ name: name, state: state }, state.prevState2: { name: name, state: state } etc.]` .  I actually think that's kind of perfect.

Comment: The idea would be to define every possible state transition and what it does to the state (like what Photoshop or Gimp does, for example) and save the transition history. Then you just apply the previous transition to undo. The exact implementation would depend on your use case

Comment: Just undoing wouldn't solve for the requirement, nor would maintaining an entire stack of transitions.  Instead, I need to be dehydrate states into a toke in one action and then be able to rehydrate the tokenized states on a link click.  That being said, I think your idea of using a stack of states is valid I just need to -as you point out above- customize the implementation.    Can you make the command pattern an answer?  I'll accept. :)

Comment: If you have the time and want some inspiration, there is a talk on youtube called "First Class Commands" by Reginald Braithwaite that shows several ways to use commands for action buffers. Not specific to redux, but still great talk

Comment: I'm always up good youtube code talks.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Command pattern. The classic example for its use case is implementing undo/redo functionality. It also lends itself nicely to redux's action -> state data flow